# Where to deal with a file exception?

Tags: java, file-io, exception

I've been working on a console based Inventory program as part of my course, and now I need to store and parse the data in files. So, I have stored all of my data in csv files and have a dedicated 'file' with a generic `loadFile()` method.

If the Inventory or config file cannot be found, it doesn't really make sense for the program to continue as everything else depends on them.

As such, I'm simply catching the file within the `loadFile()` method and printing a statement to the user and then using `System.exit()` to close.

Is this good practice? Is there a more elegant way of terminating the program after the correct error message has been printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The purpose of exceptions is to indicate exceptional conditions.  Since your program won't work without its input files, `System.exit()` is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: It depends on the program of course but for a command line program it's definitely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle it only when you can do something useful.  If you want to stop the program the simplest this to do is have your main throw IOException.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of situation I usually prefer to throw an unchecked exception from the `loadFile()` method as the program cannot recover from this situation, for example a `RuntimeException` or an `IllegalStateException`. This exception will cause the application to exit unless you decide to catch it and handle it.